# Row height not increasing based on content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]I am using bootstrap rows and columns to define the grid layout. The problem I am facing is that the height is not increasing based on the content. Instead a scroll bar appears.

I have tried specifying the height of the row and column divs as ht-100 to utilize 100% of height but it did not work.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-2" style="background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);">
    <h2>Sync Manager</h2>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-border-gray">
        <div class="row">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link text-success" id="internal-storage" href="#">Internal</a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link text-success" id="external-storage" href="#">External</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-8 col-border-gray">
        <ul>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>
          <li>Test</li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect the height of the container to increase as the amount of content increases.

Comment: Interesting. On my computer it works fine. `container` increases as the `<li>` increases in amount, without the scrollbar.

Comment: For me it doesn't. Strange. Added a screenshot.

Comment: you might have other code that is doing that. which is not in the code you shared. Check jsfiddle using your code and bs4 -> http://jsfiddle.net/prqs1o2x/

Comment: Thanks, figured it out. I was setting "ul" max height to 200px in my css. Silly me!